# different timestamp for a same code

Tags: python, datetime

i have written a code which converts date and time into timezone , now the problem is i have tired to run the code in python console and in http function but in spite of having a same code i am getting different output of timestamp

***in python console***

```
from datetime import datetime
import time
qdate="08-03-2011 05:00:00"
ttimetuple=time.strptime(qdate,"%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
print  time.mktime(ttimetuple)
```

> output is **1299578400.0**

***in webservices or http function***

```
def SaveDate(request,qdate):
        qdate="08-03-2011 05:00:00" # i hard coded for a timing to verify the timestamp
        ttimetuple=time.strptime(qdate,"%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
        data=time.mktime(ttimetuple)
        return HttpResponse(data,mimetype='application/javascript')
```

> output is 1299582000.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is because your console and web server are running under the different time zone settings.

Try

```
import time
print time.timezone
```

to check whether time zone of your console and the server is different.

Comment: i am  remotely logged in into python console which is on server side only .. so everything is on server side only.

output of the code that you suggested is 18000

Comment: @Hunt: 18000 is the number of seconds you are behind the UTC, so 5 hours to the West from Greenwich.

Comment: Well yes your are right, the problem is related to timezone  as i print the timezone in http method and its returning 21600.